# Installing egg through pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, easy-install, egg

I can successfully install egg for morfeusz2 through

```
python -m easy_install http://sgjp.pl/morfeusz/download/20181014/ubuntu-xenial/morfeusz2-0.4.0-py3.7-win-amd64.egg
```

However, all other dependencies I define through `requirements.txt`. I would like all of them to be defined in a consistent way. morfeusz2 is not present in any PyPI repo. How can I define dependencies for my project in a consistent way?

For instance, I have tried to define the following `requirements.txt` file:

```
django
pint
http://sgjp.pl/morfeusz/download/20181014/ubuntu-xenial/morfeusz2-0.4.0-py3.7-win-amd64.egg
```

However, when running `pip install -r requirements.txt` it fails with:

```
(mealplanner) D:\Projects-intellij\djangoproject\mealplanner>pip install -r requirementx.txt
Collecting http://sgjp.pl/morfeusz/download/20181014/ubuntu-xenial/morfeusz2-0.4.0-py3.7-win-amd64.egg (from -r requirementx.txt (line 3))
  Downloading http://sgjp.pl/morfeusz/download/20181014/ubuntu-xenial/morfeusz2-0.4.0-py3.7-win-amd64.egg (7.7MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 7.7MB 11.4MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\oem\virtualenv\mealplanner\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\OEM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-xucfpk6m\\setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-xucfpk6m\
```

How do I install egg with pip install?

Comment: [pip install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#argument-handling) can install sdist or wheel packages, but not eggs. In the world of pip and wheels egg is now an outdated format and should be replaced with wheels.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, the package you mentioned is now included in [PyPI](https://pypi.org): [morfeusz2 · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/morfeusz2/).
However, It's also adviceable to link to a GitHub repo (or something like that), although sadly it's not on any VCS website, but you can consider add the link on its offical website, for example:

> http://download.sgjp.pl/morfeusz/20231112/Windows/64/morfeusz2-1.99.7-20231112-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl

(for Windows and Cpython 3.11, as it's mentioned upon)

Hopefully this would solve your problem,